# Android contact picker filtered

Tags: android, filter, contacts, picker

I am looking for a way to open a Contact Picker but I wish that it show only contacts which belong to a certain group.

Is there any way to do that?

I tried a lot of parameters when instantiating the intent but without success.
I have only succeeded in opening a contact picker with the entire phone book:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_CONTACT);
```

Or opening it focused on pick a phone number:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phones.CONTENT_URI); 
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contact picker filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851892/contact-picker-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this with the stock intent and contact picker system

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.