# Contact picker filtering

Tags: android

I use the contact picker in this way:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

My question is if somehow the contact list can be filtered? For example I want to see only those contacts in the contact list which have at least a phone number or an email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use your custom view for the contacts- it is not rather difficult and you can customize it however you want. I personally implemented that way the functionality you need.

See here:

```
String PHONE_CONTACTS_ORDER_CLAUSE = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        + " ASC";

List<PhoneContact> contacts = new ArrayList<PhoneContact>(); // I have defined the bean PhoneContact
String[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }; //Choose the columns you need
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null/* the place for your where clause*/, null/* the place for your where args*/,
        PHONE_CONTACTS_ORDER_CLAUSE);
startManagingCursor(cursor);

int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
int displayNameIdx = cursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    PhoneContact contact = new PhoneContact(); // This is a class i defined, use the data the way you like.
    contact.setContactId(cursor.getString(contactIdIdx));
    contact.setDisplayName(cursor.getString(displayNameIdx));
    contacts.add(contact);
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry got distracted when writing the comment: the Contact id is actually the glue between the different content providers of the Contact related data. These are a few more providers you can use to see whether there are any associated phones or emails with the contact:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
```

Comment: A disadvantage of this approach is that it requires the `READ_CONTACTS` permission to query the Contacts provider.

Comment: @tad:alternative is always appreciated!

Comment: There is no pure alternative if you want to stick with the global Intent and not add permissions. You can only filter by one attribute at a time using `Intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE)` or `Intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE)`. If you do not want to add `READ_CONTACTS`, redesign this interaction to select by either phone or email.

Comment: @Hades some class or variable definition is missing or what? This is weird because i remember i developed and tested the code on Gingerbread…

Comment: Sorry @BorisStrandjev I made a mistake, it does work with Gingerbread, just not as a contact picker URI..